How to migrate a git repository from github to gogs
I am getting timeouts in a big CICD git repository when executing an ansible-playbook command that executes flux bootstrap on it. It takes too long to clone it from github.
I have installed a gogs git server in the same AKS kubernetes cluster where all the platform runs. This will dramatically speed the gitops operations (I'm also not confortable with using a github server in a production system so...
What would be the best approach to do a repository migration? (Can I "fork" to copy the git repository form github into my gogs git). How would I then remove the forked one (which is also a fork from the real original one)
The system is running so if I can avoid having to delete verithing and re deploy once I copy the repository it would be great.
So ideally I would like to "fork" the GitHub repo into gogs... but I am not sure if there is a way to do that.

Are you trying to move away from GitHub completely, or just have a copy of the repo closer to your infrastructure?

Depending on if you want to keep every branch ever created or not you could just add another remote locally and push master to it.

I want to keep current fork in GitHub while having a "copy" of this fork in another git service (gogs, or maybe even Azure Devops). I have found that a way to do this is just by multiple remotes for my repository so I would pull from github, branch locally, and push that branch to the git to be used for gitops (gogs, azure gitops, ...). Any thoughts on this?

Maybe a mirror repo inside gogs is what you want. I found a script with a similar usecase here
